# Question about double limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, limits-without-lhopital

I am practising the resolution of double limits after quite of a long time of not doing many calculations. Most of the exercises  I've tried didn't pose a problem, usually the squeeze theorem, the polar method or choosing carefully a pair of paths that lead to different limits do the trick.

However, now I am stuck with the following limit, and I want to **not use derivatives** (so no L'Hôpital)

$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{1}{1-\cos(x)} + \frac{2}{\sin(x)\sin(y)}
$$

Choosing the path $y = -x$ shows that, if the limit exists, it must be $+\infty$. I'd like to find a path which leads to a different limit. The path $y=x$ leads to $-\infty$, but I showed it using L'Hôpital and, as I said, I'd like to solve the limit wihout the use of derivatives. This is bugging me as I feel there is a convenient path that gives a different result, but I can't see it.

Can you help?

Comment: The two path limits seem quite similar, so I'm initially surprised you can't do the second one the same way you did the first ... can you show what you did do?

Comment: The function is not defined in any punctured neighborhood of the origin (the latter term is undefined on the coordinate axes), so it is difficult to see how it could have a limit unless your definition of a limit constrains the point $(x,y)$ to the domain. Which is certainly not unreasonable!

Comment: The terms are respectively asymptotic to $2/x^2,\,2/(xy)$, so $y=-x/2$ would be more useful than $y=-x$ if you're looking to contrast with the path $y=x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $x=y$ you want to compute
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{1}{1-\cos x}+\frac{2}{\sin^2x}\right)
$$
which definitely doesn't require l'Hôpital: the second fraction can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{2}{1-\cos^2x}
$$
and so you get
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1+\cos x+2}{1-\cos^2x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{3+\cos x}{\sin^2x}
$$
to which you *cannot* apply l'Hôpital.

With $x=-y$ you'd get
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{1}{1-\cos x}-\frac{2}{\sin^2x}\right)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1+\cos x-2}{1-\cos^2x}=\lim_{x\to0}-\frac{1}{1+\cos x}
$$
which is not $-\infty$

Comment: Thanks, I totally messed up the calculations after too much time of  practising.. It seems so obvious now